# Is it possible to fully customize ProgressBar colors in WinUI 3 using a 'plug and play' approach?

Tags: xaml, colors, progress-bar, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am working on a theme in WinUI 3, and customizing colors for many different controls.

For the Infobar control I managed to customize the colors to my liking by changing the name of the color the brush pointed to (so that it is different from the native Windows control), for instance

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="InfoBarErrorSeverityBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource CriticalBackground}"/>
```

I managed to achieve the customization for the InfoBadge control, using a similar manner for the brushes.

I tried the same tactic with ProgressBar. However, even though I was referencing a color with a different name from that of Windows, I was only able to obtain part of the result I wanted by using the ProgressBar Control and adding a specific **x:Key**, which then was referenced in the control.

This would be acceptable for many cases, but I want to distribute my custom theme via a nuget package, and I would prefer a more "plug and play" approach, where the user wouldn't need to reference the custom style.

**Is this possible to achieve in WinUI 3? What am I missing? I want to see my application work with all of its "true colors shining through".**

I tried changing the name of the color referenced, so that it is different from Windows colors. Worked for the InfoBar and InfoBadge templates, but not for ProgressBar and Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible to achieve in WinUI 3? What am I missing? I want to see my application work with all of its "true colors shining through".

As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to achieve. You couldn't fully customize ProgressBar colors in WinUI 3 using a 'plug and play' approach?.

> I tried changing the name of the color referenced, so that it is different from Windows colors. Worked for the InfoBar and InfoBadge templates, but not for ProgressBar and Combobox.

You could try to change the name of the color referenced , and it works for ProgressBar and Combobox.